# how to make list of group by clickable django

Tags: python, html, django

i made a group by list of items based on two fields

```
class Product(models.Model):
    type_of_product = models.CharField(max_length=30,default="electric)
    made_in = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=countries,default="UK")
    product= models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

views.py

```
def categories(request):
     lists = Product.objects.values('type_of_product ', 'made_in').annotate(
     total=Count('pk')
     ).order_by('type_of_product ', 'made_in')
     return render(request,'shop/categories.html',{'lists':lists})
```

it returns something like this `type_of_product : electric , made_in:UK , total:20` `type_of_product : accessory , made_in:USA , total:23` and so on

i want to make lists of categories clickable , when i click on one of them , it takes me to all products with the same features , for example i click on `type_of_product : accessory , made_in:USA , total:23` it shows a list of products (23) item which made in from USA and type of product is accessory

```html
    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 pt-3 pt-8 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 ">
      {% for i in lists %}
        <a href="{% url 'the link to products list' %}" class="transition transform cursor-pointer duration-400 hover:scale-105 hover:shadow-xl">
            <div class="h-32 overflow-hidden rounded-tl-2xl rounded-tr-2xl room"></div>
            
            <div class="items-center p-2 rounded-bl-xl rounded-br-xl bglightpurple">
                   
                <div  class="text-center rounded-lg" style="background: #534e70;">
                    <p class="inline textorange "><i class="bi bi-columns-gap"></i></p>
                    <p class="inline text-white">{{i.type_of_product}}</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mt-4 text-white">
                    <div class="text-sm">
                        <p class="inline ">{{i.product}}</p>
                        <p class="inline px-1 text-sm bg-yellow-500 rounded-lg">{{i.total}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-sm">
                        <p class="inline px-1 text-sm bg-green-500 rounded-lg">{{i.made_in}}</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
                  
            </div>

            
        </a>
        {% endfor %}
        
    </div>
```

```
def products(request):
     lists = Product.objects.filter()# how to filter it to return only that items which related to the selected category 
     return render(request,'shop/products.html',{'products':lists})
```

and how to make it in the url ?

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',categories,name='categories')
    path('products<str:what?>',products,name='products')

]
```

thank you for you help ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```py
# urls.py
path('products/<str:type_of_product>/<str:made_in>/', products, name='products')

# views.py
def products(request, type_of_product, made_in):
     lists = Product.objects.filter(type_of_product=type_of_product, made_in=made_in)
     return render(request, 'shop/products.html', {'products':lists})
```

You can then use the following in your list template to generate the URL:

```
{% url 'products' i.type_of_product i.made_in %}
```